# Why do we integrate over an entire charged object to find the total electric field in physics (what does integrating actually do?)?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, integration

I'm taking first-year university electricity and magnetism and this concept is on charged rods/rings/discs. The textbook tells us that integrating over the whole charged object gives us the total electric field
[image]

What I'm confused about is how it gives us the total electric field. I'm trying to relate it to the distance with respect to time example where if u derive that equation it gives you velocity with respect to time. But if you anti derive velocity it gives u distance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of integration is essentially summing up a very large number of very small pieces. In this case, we know how to calculate the electric field due to a single point charge, but we'd like to find the electric field due to an entire (possibly very strangely-shaped) charged object.

To do this, we break the object up into a bunch of tiny pieces which can be approximated as point charges, each with charge $\mathrm dq$.  We use the formula we already know to compute the electric field due to each point charge, and then integrate over the entire object to add all of those contributions up.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense. I think I lost the meaning of integration so this helped. thank you!

Answer (score -3):

The integration comes from the resolution of Gauss law by the Green function, this is a math result.

Comment: I think OP may not be familiar with Gauss' Law and Green's function solutions to DE's.

Comment: Trying to get some easy point on the forum, not so easy

Comment: the guys who put -3 on a good answer... seriously ? You find Gauss law in many topics, this is not a specific case of electrostatics ...

Comment: You didn't get downvoted because your answer is wrong. You got downvoted because your answer wasn't particularly helpful. Stating the result without elaborating isn't particularly a good answer and doesn't help the OP understand the answer to the question.